# Return is getting ignored

Tags: roblox

As I wanted to make a script to let the RemoteEvent only fire users in specific groups, I came upon a error

Even if I am not in the groups, it is still continuing to fire the Servers even if not allowed to
so the "else" is getting ignored

```
if player:IsInGroup(7503826) or (7467047) then
       print("InGroup")
    else
       warn("Not in Intelligence Agency, Either in Internal Security Department")
       return 
end
```

I made a pcall function to check if it was Sucessful or if it Failed

```
local success, message = pcall(player, PlayerToBlind)
if success then
print("Success")
else
print("Failed")
end
```

And it always printed me "failed"

Any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition will always return true. It should be

```
if player:IsInGroup(7503826) or player:IsInGroup(7467047) then
```

`(7467047)` alone as an expression will always be true.